# Do i need BackgroundWorker or not?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

i'm writing some kind of application that will send http requests to server. My app will send requests with some interval by timer. for example, i need to send 1 type of requests with time interval 2 seconds, 2nd type of requests - 10 seconds and so on. 
i understand that it is better to have one scheduler that will push my requests. but the question is how can i send requests and process responses without freezing ui?

p.s. right now i have class MyAdapter, which encapsulates all work with requests and responses, and class MyScheduler, which sends requests by timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should indeed then use a BackGroundWorker and if you need to update the UI in the meantime, you can use the Dispatcher.Invoke() method.

Comment: I agree completely with @Abbas, my only comment to his/her suggestion would be that Dispatcher.Invoke() is available if your application is a WPF app; if you're under Windows Forms you would use `Control.Invoke()` to safely interact with the user interface from your BackgroundWorker process. I recently responded to a similar question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370655/allowing-user-interaction/9371623#9371623). You can see there an example of using `Control.Invoke()`.

Answer (score 1):

> but the question is how can i send requests and process responses without freezing ui?

You could [use timers](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/timers.shtml) to send your requests at regular intervals. If you need to update your UI when the request succeeds you might need to use the `Dispatcher.Invoke` or `Control.Invoke`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a variety of options for performing work in the background while the UI stays responsive:

- **Old, but reliable:** [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) has been around the .net Framework for a long time and would work perfectly fine for your requirements. [Lots of examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2200793/87698) can be found on this site and elsewhere.
- **State of the art**: The `Task` class, available since .NET 4, is [considered to be an improvement over BackgroundWorker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513432/task-parallel-library-replacement-for-backgroundworker).
- **Brand new**: The [`Async` extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg316360) are the *new way* to do "background stuff". No need for multi-threading and manual synchronization, everything "just works". However, this is just at "community preview" stage at the moment.